# What would be the correct design for wrapping an existing library?

Tags: .net, class, parent-child

I have done a couple of small personal projects in .NET and following the advice on SO have decided to do something a bit more advanced so that I can learn as I go.

At the moment I am writing a project to enhance an existing third-party library so that its objects may be consumed easier by another application that I will write.

In the third-party library, I am concentrating on one object, let's call it `DataSource` and this in turns contains results pertaining to a database. For a small example (the objects here have a lot more methods and properties not shown), this has a "tree" of properties as follows:

`A_DataSet -> A_Result -> A_Dimensions() -> A_Dimension -> A_SetDisplayType(DisplayAs)`

Here the `Result` object has a property called `Dimensions` which contains a collection of `Dimension`. Finally each `Dimension` has a method called `SetDisplayType` which controls the display of the data contained within another property in `Dimension`. The elements are prefixed with `A_` just for the purposes of this example.

Now, as the third-party library's methods and properties are sometimes confusing to use and numerous in nature, I wanted to create a "wrapper" to this library so that I simplify its use and structure. After quite a bit of deliberation on how to more logically group elements, I thought about going in the following direction with the structure:

`B_DataSet -> B_Dimensions() -> B_Dimension -> B_DisplayProperties -> B_SetDisplayType(DisplayAs)`

In this example, I prefixed the objects with `B_` just to distinguish them from the existing elements above, of course this is not the final naming convention (actually naming doesn't really matter for the purposes of this question).

The point that I am stuck on is how I should properly reference the third-party objects (A_*) from the wrapper class. For example, if I wanted to use `B_SetDisplayType` then this would internally call `A_SetDisplayType`. However, since `A_SetDisplayType` belongs to `A_Dimension` then I would need a reference to `A_Dimension` in `B_DisplayProperties`.
Is it okay when creating objects to pass them a reference to their "parent" in their constructor? I was thinking about something like the following code:

```
Public Class DataSetDisplayProperties

    Private _A_Dimension as A_Dimension

    Public Sub New(MyDimension as A_Dimension)

        _A_Dimension = MyDimension

    End Sub

    Public Sub B_SetDisplayType(DisplayAs as Integer)

        Call _A_Dimension.A_SetDisplayType(DisplayAs)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Does this seem fine, or is there a better method?

I was thinking about using a facade, but was unsure of how this would work when I am trying to reference methods at different "levels" to what the existing structure is.

Please note that I cannot inherit from any of the third-party classes and cannot change the code of them.

Apologies if the above seems a bit confused, I think I perhaps don't know the correct terminology for how to express my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not seem like an answer to this question, certainly not a direct one, but stay with me.  First of all I think you are right when you say you want to build a Facade.  Can I suggest that you use a Test Driven Development approach to develop the interface for this facade and then you can focus on how to implement that interface using the third party library.  This will enable you to clear your mind of the idiosyncrasies and naming conventions of the third party library and focus purely the interface that want to provide and what you want it to achieve.  It will also result in a unit test suite around your Facade implementation.

If you havn't used TDD before then you have quite a curve to go through, but I can assure you it is well worth the investment.  In terms of tools I recommend NUnit and MOQ.  You may also need an IoC container, like Unity 2.0.

Good Luck!